# VBA Word Array - Fastest way to compare items

Tags: arrays, vba

maybe this has been asked before, but if so, I couldn't figure out a way to search for it. In that case, apologies.

In Word VBA I'm looking for the fastest way to compare every item in an array with all the previous ones. Since those are many, I would like to optimize. (This would be a programmatic array in memory, not something like a spreadsheet or table or some such.)

The elements to compare are short strings of all same length, as in "0012" or "1023". Since they represent numbers, first question:

Is it faster to compare strings or to convert the items into integers first, and then compare those? Of course, in order to do that, the time to convert strings into numbers would have to be counted, too.

The comparison has to go each time a new item is added to the array. Several thousand times. Second question thus:

Is there maybe an algorithm to do this (like one would use e.g. bubble sort for sorting)?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Best,
Dieter

Comment: Is your goal to only keep the unique elements in the array? Have you thought of using a collection instead of an array?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Scripting.Dictionary`. If you're trying to build an array of unique objects, this is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks! Can I compare several of those Dictionaries with each other?

Comment: trincots question was the most important one. Indeed I need to keep all duplicates, I just have to connect them to the old values as well, which is what this is all about. So I can't use the Dictionary. Wasn't sure on Collection either. Solved it with a very special userdefined type instead. Now working. THX everyone!

Comment: Of course, the original questions weren't answered: Is it faster to compare longs or strings, and is there a superfast algorithm? Best, Dieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's comment

this code could get you started along the `Dictionary` way:

```
Sub minna()
    Dim vals As Variant, val As Variant
    Dim dict As Dictionary

    vals = Array("0012", "1023", "0013", "1023", "0014", "0012") '<--| fill your array

    Set dict = New Dictionary '<--| instantiate a dictionary object
    With dict '<--| reference your dictionary object
        For Each val In vals '<--| loop through array
            .item(val) = .item(val) + 1 '<--| fill dictionary with unique values (duplicates are automatically discharged)
        Next

        For Each val In .Keys '<--| loop through dictionary keys. i.e. array unique values
            Debug.Print "Item " & val & " has " & .item(val) & "occurrences" '<--| show haow many occurrences of every array value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

in order to use `Dictionary` object you have to add its library to your project references: Tools-> References-> scroll listbox till "Microsoft Scripting Runtime", toggle its checkmark to checked and click"OK" button

---

to handle a 2D array you could use this helper `Function`

```
Function GetDictionaryFromArray(vals As Variant) As Dictionary
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim iVal As Long

    Set dict = New Dictionary
    With dict '<--| reference your dictionary object
        For iVal = 1 To UBound(vals) '<--| loop through passed array
            .item(vals(iVal, 1)) = vals(iVal, 2) '<--| fill dictionary with unique values (duplicates are automatically discharged)
        Next
    End With

    Set GetDictionaryFromArray = dict
End Function
```

that you could exploit in your "main" code as follows:

```
Sub Main ()
    Dim vals1(1 To 6, 1 To 2) As Variant, vals2(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Variant, val As Variant, key As Variant
    Dim dict1 As Dictionary, dict2 As Dictionary
    Dim iVal As Long

    vals1(1, 1) = "0012": vals1(1, 2) = "a"
    vals1(2, 1) = "1023": vals1(2, 2) = "b"
    vals1(3, 1) = "0013": vals1(3, 2) = "c" '<--| this will survive in the conversion to dictionary
    vals1(4, 1) = "1023": vals1(4, 2) = "d" '<--| this will survive in the conversion to dictionary
    vals1(5, 1) = "0014": vals1(5, 2) = "e" '<--| this will survive in the conversion to dictionary
    vals1(6, 1) = "0012": vals1(6, 2) = "f" '<--| this will survive in the conversion to dictionary

    vals2(1, 1) = "0012": vals2(1, 2) = "a" '<--| this will survive in the conversion to dictionary
    vals2(2, 1) = "1023": vals2(2, 2) = "b"
    vals2(3, 1) = "0013": vals2(3, 2) = "c" '<--| this will survive in the conversion to dictionary
    vals2(4, 1) = "1023": vals2(4, 2) = "d" '<--| this will survive in the conversion to dictionary

    Set dict1 = GetDictionaryFromArray(vals1) '<--| make a 'Dictionary' object out of first 2D array
    Set dict2 = GetDictionaryFromArray(vals2) '<--| make a 'Dictionary' object out of second 2D array

    With dict1 '<--| reference your first dictionary object
        For Each key In .Keys '<--| loop through referenced dictionary keys. i.e. first array column 1 unique values
            If dict2.Exists(key) Then '<--| if second dictionary has the same key
                Debug.Print "Item (" & key & "," & .item(key) & ") in first array has the following corresponding item in second: (" & key & "," & dict2(key) & ")" '<--| show how many occurrences of first dictionary keys in the second dictionary
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou. This might take me a day to prove. Because the array has two dimensions, one of which contains the abovementioned numbers. The other one is filled accordingly and the intent indeed is using it like a dictionary: strings in one dimension are to correlate with strings in the other one.

Comment: see edited code for some additional code to handle 2D array and compare different dictionaries

Comment: Thanks user<long>, but the dictionary doesn't work for this case. But it's not lost, I needed your input to get that straight! THX, Dieter

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your question then you may want to mark it as accepted. If it proved useful you may also up-vote it. Thank you!

Comment: sorry, looks like I can't upvote - 15 credits or less don't vote. Odd. At least I could accept it. Dieter